# Set modal title

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have my modal:

```
<div id="defaultModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Modal Title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" data-table="table" data-id="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have my button:

```
<button  href="page.php" data-title="New Data" class='call-modal btn btn-success' > 
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
</button>
```

And after click the button I use the class "call-modal":

```
$('.call-modal').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#defaultModal')
    .find('.modal-header > h3').text("Teste").end()            
    .find('.modal-body').load($(this).attr('href')).end()            
    .modal('show');
});
```

I can load the content but I would like to set the Title using the data-title.

Any idea why it is not working?

Thank you

Comment: [Not having an issue](http://www.bootply.com/aFodNF1hWI)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$('#defaultModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button  = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal 
    var modal       = $(this);
    var title = button.data('title'); alert(title);
    modal.find('.modal-title').text(title)
});
```

and your button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#defaultModal" data-title="New Data" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bhumi/hw154nda/1/

Answer (score 4):

You can set the title once the modal is shown,

```
$('#defaultModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   $(this).find('h3#modal-title').text("You new title");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the title:

```
$("#defaultModal").dialog("option","title", "You new title");
```

Comment: Well. perhaps you can at some point. but this for sure doesn't work all the time.

Answer (score 0):

$('#modal-title').text('Any title you want!');